# Expected indentfier '('

Tags: objective-c

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground.
}
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
```

The error is coming up at the bracket on the bottom.  If you could help I would be very grateful; thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I retagged the question Objective-C (from C) since the notation (especially the `-` at the beginning of a line) is not C but could be Objective C.

Answer (score 3):

Take out the bracket. There should be no bracket there. The bracket is what is causing your problems. If you remove the bracket, your problems will go away. This is because your problems are being caused by that very bracket. If you remove the bracket then your code will look like this:

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground.
}
// !$*UTF8*$!
```

At this point, you will then cease to have this issue. You might have other issues, but not this one, because this issue is caused by the errant bracket, so removing that bracket will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer below assumes you were trying to write C, which is what the OP tagged it. It's since been pointed out OP was trying to write Objective C)

You need to go read how to define functions in C.

1. The leading `void` should not be in parentheses (brackets)
2. The second function definition begins with a `-` for no good reason
3. There is a stray colon after the function name (I'm assuming you weren't trying to write C++, in which case you'd want two colons and a class name AND member name)
4. The bit in brackets should say `(UIApplication *) application`
5. You have a final stray open `{`

So in summary you want something like:

```
void applicationDidBecomeActive (UIApplication *application)
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

void applicationWillTerminate (UIApplication *application)
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground.
}
```

Comment: I retagged the question Objective C because the notation is valid in Objective C (but is completely invalid in C, as you say).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks - well I wasted my time there then. Perhaps OP now knows how to write C a bit too.